# What is the STATE column of the TOP command on Solaris?

Tags: solaris, top

I'm running a very large, memory intensive program on my new UNIX server and trying to fully understand the output of the "top" command.  Here is what I see right now (showing only the first process):

```
load averages:  1.51,  1.48,  1.45;               up 59+12:23:36                              08:57:47
194 processes: 191 sleeping, 1 zombie, 2 on cpu
CPU states: 99.5% idle,  0.4% user,  0.1% kernel,  0.0% iowait,  0.0% swap
Kernel: 2045 ctxsw, 73 trap, 2891 intr, 1797 syscall, 23 flt, 48 pgout
Memory: 256G phys mem, 214G free mem, 22G total swap, 22G free swap

   PID USERNAME LWP PRI NICE  SIZE   RES STATE    TIME    CPU COMMAND
 15382 bd9439    22   1    4 7799M 7787M cpu/147  21.9H  0.39% sas
```

What is the meaning of the number in the "STATE" column following "cpu" (in this case 147)?  The `man` page only says:

```
 STATE
      Current state (typically one of "sleep", "run",  "idl",
      "zomb", or "stop").
```

This is a new Oracle T4-4 server running Solaris 10 not yet in "production", meaning this is the only thing running right now.

Solaris 10 and top version 3.7:

```
bd9439@bsprd697 $ uname -a
SunOS bsprd697 5.10 Generic_148888-01 sun4v sparc sun4v
bd9439@bsprd697 $ top --version
top: version 3.7
```

Comment: What version of solaris and top are we talking here? `top --version`.

Comment: Is it just this row that shows it this way or all of them, or some of them?

Comment: Did you accidentally hit either the `t` or `H` keys? Look through this man page: http://www.unixtop.org/man.shtml. There are sections for Solaris that might be tripping you up.

Comment: @slm Thanks for the link; that man page does describe the meaning of that number after the slash (as answered below).  It's not in the man page on my system.

Comment: That's usually the case with the man pages on Solaris 8-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number refers to the ID# of the logical CPU that the process is running on.

#### References

- [top man page](http://www.unixtop.org/man.shtml)

Comment: Yep, that's it.  The link to the man page provided by slm in a comment has a complete description.

Answer (score 3):

**STATE** = the state of the process (this is taken from `prstat` command man page):

- cpuN - Process is running on CPU N.
- sleep - Sleeping: process is waiting for an  event  to  complete.
- wait -Waiting: process is waiting for CPU usage to drop to the CPU-caps enforced limits. See the description of CPU-caps in resource_controls(5).
- run - Runnable: process in on run queue.
- zombie - Zombie state:  process  terminated  and  parent  not waiting.
- stop - Process is stopped.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm asking about the number following the word "cpu" in the report, in this case `cpu/147`. I don't know what the `147` means.

Comment: Yo have 4 T4 processors, each with 8 cores and each can handle 8 threads, so in total 256 logical thread units where 147 is one of them.